About admob interstitial ads display gp details page on interstitial video play completed
Why do some admob video interstitial ads automatically display the gp download page after playing?
As shown below ：

I did not click on this ad. The gp details page popped up automatically after the video ad was played.
Is this effect configured through the admob background? Or is it implemented in code?
I want to know how this advertising effect is achieved。
